# Return more than one number from a function in python

Tags: python, while-loop

I have written a function like this:

```
def collatz(number):
    '''
        Function takes a positive integer x as input and prints the Collatz sequence starting at x
    '''
    while True:
        if number % 2 == 0: # If number is even
            number = number/2
            return number
        elif number == 1:
            break
        else:
            number =  3*number+1
            return number
```

The function is supposed to return number like this:

```
collatz(10)
10
5
16
8
4
2
1
```

This function works with the following formula:

```
X={x/2 if x is even , if 3x+1  if x is odd
```

Right now it's returning only 1 number. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you return something that means the function is done

you could just `append` the numbers to a list and then return the list of numbers that way it would finish all the iterations of the while loop instead of stopping after one

Answer (score 1):

After a function returns something it immediately breaks. Consider using `yield`:

```
def collatz(number):
    '''
        Function takes a positive integer x as input and prints the Collatz sequence starting at x
    '''
    while True:
        if number % 2 == 0: # If number is even
            number = number/2
            yield number
        elif number == 1:
            break
        else:
            number =  3*number+1
            yield number
```

This will then return a generator with the numbers. You can do `list(collatz(n))` to get a list of the numbers.